# setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) not working in onResume() method

Tags: android, visibility

Started an Activity B from  Activity A without finishing A.  if the Activity B is finished,i have written a method inside `onResume()` of Activity A to make an `ImageView` invisible. But this is not working. Code is given below.

```
public void onResume()
{
    if(preferenceUtil.getMUSIC_ONOFF()==0) {
        try {
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    giftbutton.setEnabled(true);
    giftbutton.setClickable(true);

    checkUnlockedStory();
    super.onResume();
}

  public void checkUnlockedStory()
        {
             if(preferenceUtil.getOVERALL_STARS()>=24)
            {                 
                    giftbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.gift);
                    giftbutton_count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                  

            }
   }
```

Comment: Have you checked whether onResume() of Activity A is calling while returning from Activity B to Activity A?

Comment: try debugging, hard to tell if your "overall stars" is really >= 24 and the code inside the 'if' gets called.

Comment: @Sachin Saxena OnResume() of Activity A is getting called while returning from Activity B. Same way the line of code  giftbutton_count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    also executed but still the view is visible

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have override onResume method:

```
@Override
protected void OnResume()
{
super.onResume();
//Type your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
giftbutton_count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong id ,might be missing this

giftbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers, you might need to do `yourView.clearAnimation();` after `yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`, since your view might already start animation once which causes extra layer still remains visible.